# How to generate 3d array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have tried the following:

```
int ax=32;  
int ay=32;  
int az=32;  
int Blocks[32][32][32];  
for(ax){  
    for(ay){  
        for{az}{  
            Blocks[ax][ay][az]=1;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

But that produces error: excepted ';' before ')' token.
What am i doing wrong?
Also is there any better ways of setting every slot of an array to same value?

Comment: `for(ax)` is not a [valid syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

Comment: Either create a 1d array and map the indices, use an `int***` dynamically, or triple nest a container like `std::array` or `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it with vectors:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
int main()
{
    int maxX=32, maxY=32, maxZ=32;
    vector<vector<vector<int> > > int3Darray;
    // Set up sizes. (maxX x maxY)
    int3Darray.resize(maxX);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxX; ++i)
    {
        int3Darray[i].resize(maxY);
        for (int j = 0; j < maxY; ++j)
            int3Darray[i][j].resize(maxZ);
    }
    //set each field to 1
    for(int i=0; i<maxX; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<maxY; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<maxZ; k++)
                int3Darray[i][j][k] = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you dont need all those loops if you pass the size to the constructor

Comment: All the code that you have written could be simplified into a single line: `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> int3Darray (maxX, std::vector<std::vector<int>> (maxY, std::vector<int> (1, maxZ)));`